# Icons not showing in powershell after installing posh-git

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code, posh-git, oh-my-posh

Today I installed posh-git in the PowerShell but the icons are not showing instead showing a rectangle box with a question mark inside. Below are the steps I followed to:

`Install-Module oh-my-posh -Scope CurrentUser`

then

`Install-Module posh-git -Scope CurrentUser`

For both packages, I have selected the **Yes To All** option.

After installing the packages, I opened  `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` file and added the following snippet:

```
Import-Module oh-my-posh
Import-Module posh-git

Set-PoshPrompt -Theme M365Princess
# M365Princess is the theme name I found from oh-my-posh doc
```

After this in the VS Code `settings.json` I added this `"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Fira Code"`.

FYI, I have installed the `Fira Code Medium Nerd Font Complete Windows Compatible` font already.

Then restarted by VS Code. Color is showing perfectly and also some icons but also some are missing like the example in the below screenshot.

[image: Posh Git]

Please help me out with how I can solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oh-my-posh themes not working correctly with Powerline font and ConEmu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61479157/oh-my-posh-themes-not-working-correctly-with-powerline-font-and-conemu)

Comment: You have to change you fonts, personaly  I use CaskaydiaCove Nerd font. Have a look to [How to make a pretty prompt in Windows Terminal with Powerline, Nerd Fonts, Cascadia Code, WSL, and oh-my-posh](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-make-a-pretty-prompt-in-windows-terminal-with-powerline-nerd-fonts-cascadia-code-wsl-and-ohmyposh)

Answer (score 3):

Use the recommended font from oh my posh
https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/releases/download/v2.1.0/Meslo.zip

More info at https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/installation/fonts

[oh my posh fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJkie.png)

Answer (score 3):

I was leading with the same problem. This solved it for me.

Install one of the nerd fonts recommended by oh-my-posh

```bash
oh-my-posh font install # Add --user if you're not running as administrator
```

Once that they are installed, you should change the properties of the command shell. For example, I selected Meslo font. In windows terminal, you change the settings.json and add:

```json
{
    "profiles":
    {
        "defaults":
        {
            "font":
            {
                "face": "MesloLGM Nerd Font"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In PowerShell, you go to `properties > fonts` and select one of nerd fonts.

If you need to charge the profile again, you can do it with `. $PROFILE`.

Comment: I think the command is `oh-my-posh font install`, not `oh-my-posh install fonts`. Also even after doing that the posh fonts are not presented in the list of fonts when going to the terminal's "Properties" -> "Fonts" menu.

Comment: You're right. I fixed the command. I don't know why you're not able to find the fonts in the menu. After selecting and installing a font from oh-my-posh, I'm able to find the family font that I installed. Doesn't it appear even after resetting the terminal?

Comment: @jeancallisti , I installed other font and it appears in the Properties - Font menu without resetting the terminal. I'm using PowerShell 7.3.8.

Answer (score 1):

Two things, first, do not use the module anymore as that's no longer supported. More info [here](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/migrating). Secondly, [set the correct font](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/installation/fonts) so the icons can render, as that's why you see

Comment: Hey @Jan, I tried with multiple fonts even saw some answers in stack and tried those also. What I noticed is my IntelliJ integrated powershell is showing the icons properly but not in VS Code or windows default powershell

Comment: hey @BarefacedBear you do need to adjust the font settings for all terminals. That's not something oh-my-posh can do for you.